# VueRouter and meta fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

According to the VueRouter documentation, it is possible to add [meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) and globally restrict routes based on their values.

After attempting an implementation as outlined, I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: record is not defined (line 46)
```

Which corresponds to this line:

```
if (!hasCookies(record.meta.cookies)) {
```

Here is the file that has the router-guard logic:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  { 
    path : '/authenticate/:id', 
    component : require ('./components/authenticate.vue'),
    redirect: '/here',
  },

  // can only get here if the passcode has been filled out
  {
    path : '/client/create',
    component : require('./components/createClientForm.vue'),
    meta : {
      cookies: ['passcode_cookie'], // need passcode to be able to create the client
      redirect: '/authenticate/1' // dummy value here for now
    }
  },

  // can only get here if passcode and client form have been completed
  {
    path : '/test/:id',
    component : require('./components/runTest.vue'),
    meta : {
      cookies : ['passcode_cookie', 'client_cookie'],
      redirect : '/client/create'
    }
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter ({
  routes,
  mode: 'history',
});

  function hasCookies (cookies) {
    return cookies.every(cookie => document.cookie.indexOf(cookie) !== -1);
  }

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.cookies)) {
      // this route requires cookies, check if cookies exist
      if (!hasCookies(record.meta.cookies)) {
        next({
          path : record.meta.redirect || '/',
        })
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next(); // make sure to always call next()!
    }
  });

const app = new Vue ({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory here. The variable `record` is not in scope, it's not a function parameter and it's not a global variable. `record` is defined only within the callback function you passed to `some`. It's out of scope at the point where the error occurs.

Try this instead:

```js
const record = to.matched.find(record => record.meta.cookies && !hasCookies(record.meta.cookies));
if (record) {
  next({ path: record.meta.redirect || '/' });
} else {
  next();
}
```